# Converting pandas index to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following datetime string in pandas index:

```
2022-04-04T09:15:00-05:00
```

I am trying to convert this to a datetime object with this:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.index).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

But for some reason the index value is this:

```
Index(['1970-01-01T00:00:00',
```

Could you please advise as to why it is not recognizing the dates?

Comment: it works as expected for me on the string you included.

Comment: I am now getting this: `1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000  2021-01-22T09:15:00+05:00` as index value. How do i get rid of 1970?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual index being converted is 0.
If you do:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([1])
df.index=[0]
pd.to_datetime(df.index).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

You will see that:

```
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000
```

actually corresponds to 0 in Datetime format.

My guess is that you need to df.set_index to your date string before calling

```
pd.to_datetime(df.index).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```